# Express-Edge Template Engine looks for wrong URL

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, template-engine

I think there is something wrong with my `app.set('views', ${__dirname}/views`) configuration, because it looks for `/firstRoute/css` when I request a URL with `firstRoute/someRoute` recent. Apart from that everything works just with single routes like `/`    or    `/someRoute` etc

```
'http://localhost:4000/posts/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

instead of:

```
'http://localhost:4000/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css'
```

and this is my index.js file:

```
    const path = require('path');
const expressEdge = require("express-edge");
const express = require("express");
const edge = require("edge.js");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");
const bodyParser = require("body-parser");
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload");
const expressSession = require('express-session');
const connectMongo = require('connect-mongo');
const connectFlash = require("connect-flash");

const createPostController = require('./controllers/createPost');
const homePageController = require('./controllers/homePage');
const storePostController = require('./controllers/storePost');
const getPostController = require('./controllers/getPost');
const createUserController = require("./controllers/createUser");
const storeUserController = require('./controllers/storeUser');
const logoutController = require("./controllers/logout");

const loginController = require("./controllers/login");
const loginUserController = require('./controllers/loginUser');


const app = new express();
app.use(express.static("public"));
app.use(expressEdge);
app.set('views', `${__dirname}/views`);


mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/aomerk', { 
    useCreateIndex : true,
    useNewUrlParser: true })
    .then(() => 'You are now connected to Mongo!')
    .catch(err => console.error('Something went wrong', err));

app.use(connectFlash());

const mongoStore = connectMongo(expressSession);

app.use(expressSession({
    secret: 'secret',
    saveUninitialized : true,
    store: new mongoStore({
        mongooseConnection: mongoose.connection
    })
}));
app.use('*', (req, res, next) => {
    edge.global('auth', req.session.userId)
    next()
});
app.use(fileUpload());


app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ extended: true }));


const storePost = require('./middleware/storePost');
const auth = require("./middleware/auth");
const redirectIfAuthenticated = require('./middleware/redirectIfAuthenticated')


app.get("/", homePageController);
app.get("/post/:id", getPostController);
app.get("/posts/new", auth, createPostController);
app.post("/posts/store", auth, storePost, storePostController);
app.get("/auth/login", redirectIfAuthenticated, loginController);
app.post("/users/login", redirectIfAuthenticated, loginUserController);
app.get("/auth/register", redirectIfAuthenticated, createUserController);
app.post("/users/register", redirectIfAuthenticated, storeUserController);
app.get("/auth/logout", redirectIfAuthenticated, logoutController);


app.listen(4000, () => {
  console.log("App listening on port 4000");
});
```

Comment: Where is the HTML that loads the CSS? What is the URL of the CSS being loaded? Have you checked it is correct? What is the *complete* error message that you receive? Look at the Network tab in the browser's developer tools. Is it actually CSS that you are loading?

Comment: /posts and /posts/new are using the same file, 'create'. First is rendering correctly but latter is not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was with the head of my main template file. I was loading css files:

```
  <link href="vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

but instead I should have

```
  <link href="/vendor/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
```

The '/' at the beginning tells href it should look for the root.